# How can I use applyInPandas with index along side the groupby value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's assume I have a DataFrame with an `id` column, and I apply on it an applyInPnadas function this way -

```
def foo(key, pdf: pd.DataFrame):
   do_something(key, pdf)

df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(foo, schema=schema)
```

But I want the foo function to run multiple times on each id and the logic to depend on the index. For example, if my index is `index=7`, I want each id will be sent 7 times - first time with 1, then with 2, 3 ,4 ...7 . Something like this -

```
def foo(key, index, pdf: pd.DataFrame):
   do_something(key, index, pdf)

df.groupby("id", range(index)).applyInPandas(foo, schema=schema)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not calling multiple times the `do_something` (or multiple other methods) then put everything in a dict and return it as a dataframe? Just to give you an idea.